# How to tell if traffic is hitting a block of addresses

Tags: networking

I am currently working on a system that will be used to monitor traffic that is sent to a block of addresses.

The way this machine is configured, all of the addresses in this block are routed to a single interface on the machine. When I run the command `ip addr`, instead of a single IP address being displayed next to where it says `inet`, it reads as a block of addresses. An example would be `10.10.10.10/20`.

How would I go about making sure that traffic is successfully hitting this block of addresses?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `tcpdump` to get an idea what is going on. Run

```
sudo tcpdump -i <ifname>
```

on the machine. Then from another machine, try pinging each of your addresses. The terminal running `tcpdump` should show the ping request and reply.